# Sorting within row (conditional)

Tags: r, data.table

I need to sort values for some columns per row, but only if some other reference columns for same row have identical values (skipping NA and NULL). The columns are of different types (to sort are characters, reference are lists).

MWE below. Only row 2 should NOT be sorted. DT.is is the data.table to use, and DT.want is what is needed.

```
library(data.table)
DT.is <- data.table(Col_A=c("V2", "V2", "V2", "V2"),
                                 Col_B=c("V3", "V3", "V1", "V1"),
                                 Col_C=c("V1", "V1", NA_character_, NA_character_),
                                 Ref_A=list(c("RA", "RB"), "RB", "RA", "RA"),
                                 Ref_B=list(c("RA", "RB"), c("RA", "RB"), "RA", "RA"),
                                 Ref_C=list(c("RA", "RB"), "RA", NULL, NA_character_))

DT.want <- data.table(Col_A=c("V1", "V2", "V1", "V1"),
                                        Col_B=c("V2", "V3", "V2", "V2"),
                                        Col_C=c("V3", "V1", NA_character_, NA_character_),
                                        Ref_A=list(c("RA", "RB"), "RB", "RA", "RA"),
                                        Ref_B=list(c("RA", "RB"), c("RA", "RB"), "RA", "RA"),
                                        Ref_C=list(c("RA", "RB"), "RA", NULL, NA_character_))
```

The original data.table has many rows.

Comment: why is row 2 the only one not sorted?

Comment: Row 2 has different ref-values, other rows have same.

Comment: If your real data has only ABC columns there's only 4 possible situation so we can hard-core those and have a solution that will look simpler than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been quite a ride :) :

I have no idea how to do it with `data.table` so here's a `tidyverse` solution :

```
library(tidyverse)
DT.is %>%
  rownames_to_column %>%
  gather(key,value,-1) %>%
  separate(key,c("type","V")) %>%
  spread(type,value) %>%
  mutate(Ref2=as.character(Ref),
         Col = unlist(Col)) %>%
  group_by(rowname,Ref2) %>%
  mutate(Col = sort(Col,na.last=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-Ref2) %>%
  gather(type,value,Col,Ref) %>%
  unite(key,type,V) %>%
  spread(key,value) %>%
  as.data.table

#    rowname Col_A Col_B Col_C Ref_A Ref_B Ref_C
# 1:       1    V1    V2    V3 RA,RB RA,RB RA,RB
# 2:       2    V2    V3    V1    RB RA,RB    RA
# 3:       3    V1    V2    NA    RA    RA  NULL
# 4:       4    V1    V2    NA    RA    RA    NA
```

I'm first converting to long format because this way i'll be able to group by your `Ref` values. Then I sort by initial row id and `Ref` value (converted to character temporarily as one can't group by list) and then I climb all the way abck to initial format.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not at tidyverser, so I'm studying this slowly :D

Comment: It's tough for an initiation then :). Run it line by line and hopefully you'll get what's going on. Ask if something's obscure.